# Saving custom payment field data in magento 2 through plugin not working,

Tags: magento2, payment, plugin, extension-attributes

I am trying to save my custom field data through plugin but it's not working.

**Plugin Class**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Checkout;

class PaymentInformationManagementPlugin {

    protected $paymentMethodManagement;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quote, 
        \Magento\Quote\Api\PaymentMethodManagementInterface $paymentMethodManagement
    ) {
        $this->paymentMethodManagement = $paymentMethodManagement;
        $this->quoteManagement = $quoteManagement;
    }    

    public function beforeSavePaymentInformation(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement $subject, 
$cartId, 
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface $paymentInformation
    ) {
        //$paymentInformation->getData('extension_attributes');
        $extenstinAttributes = $paymentInformation->getExtensionAttributes();
        $taxCode = $extenstinAttributes->getTaxCode();

        $paymentInformation->setExtensionAttributes($taxCode);
        $this->paymentMethodManagement->set($cartId, $paymentInformation);

        return true;
//        var_dump($taxCode);exit;
//        $quote=$this->quote->create();
//        $quote->getPayment()->setData('tax_code',$taxCode);
//        return $paymentInformation;
    }

}
```

extenstion_attribute.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface">
        <attribute code="tax_code" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement">
        <plugin name="save-in-quote-payment" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Checkout\PaymentInformationManagementPlugin" sortOrder="12349"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Can anyone please help me on this.

Comment: show more detail with config

Comment: i am getting the value $taxCode = $extenstinAttributes->getTaxCode(); in this variable  but unable to set he data.

Comment: please check the update code in question

Comment: i am getting the form data in my plugin but unable to save data.

Comment: Did you done this?

Answer (score 0):

I think that for start you need to set the extension attributes like this:

```
$extensionAttributes = $paymentInformation->getExtensionAttributes();
$extensionAttributes->setTaxCode('something');
$paymentInformation->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);
```

You can try this approach and let me know how you get on.